# Jekyll custom date in Github Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

> **This is now fix**
>
> I want to have custom date, in my language. For example, instead of
>   `08 Feb 2015`, I could have `08 Février 2015`. How can I change this,
>   in my Jekyll website?
>
> My problem is that I am hosted by Github Pages, so no plugins is
>   allowed.
>
> PS: I check [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372925/jekyll-custom-date), but it's wasn't ansewerd.

Also, my similar content is always redirected to the domain `0.0.7.222`, how can I fix this?

This is the code of related content;

```
<div class="related">
  <h2>Contenu relié</h2>
  <ul class="related-posts">
    {% for post in site.related_posts limit:3 %}
      <li>
        <h3>
          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">
            {{ post.title }}
            <small>{% include custom_date_full_fr.html date = post.date %}</small>
          </a>
        </h3>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

From [Lanyon theme](https://github.com/poole/lanyon).

Tanks

Comment: I've made an answer about how to output custom internationalised dates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28411070/1548376).

Comment: Can you show us some code concerning you redirect ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Sure, check out the questions, just add it. And, thanks for your answers, it was huseful.

Comment: More useful, the repository url please. I've got an idea, but I want to confirm my thoughts.

Comment: The github repo is [felixinx/felixinx.github.io](https://github.com/felixinx/felixinx.github.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I get it.

#### setting baseurl

As your serving from a root subdomain, you have to set `baseurl` to `""`.

```
baseurl: ""
```

#### linking to page and resources

Link to a post or page via this url is `{{site.baseurl}}{{page.url}}` because a page/post url is prefixed with **/**.

Link to resource like css or js or image need an extra **/**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/public/css/poole.css">
```

Comment: It's take my a bit of time, but it's resolved. This theme is not perfect with `baseurl` and `url`. I need to change a lot of things and file, but its OK. Thanks